# How to evaluate values stored in column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, types

I want to "evaluate" the values stored in a column of the dataframe.

In this case, the column name is 'LS'.

When I query `df['LS'].head(4)`,

I get:

```
0    88+2
1    91+3
2    84+3
4    82+3
Name: LS, dtype: object
```

I want 'LS' to store `[90,94,87,85,...]`

What should I do?
Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You can just evaluate the strings with `df.LS.map(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: For a pandas solution `df['LS'] = pd.eval(df.LS)`.

Comment: @yatu Thanks for your quick response; when I applied this command, I got "ValueError: malformed string" error. What does malformed string mean? I think the input is fairly straightforward and valuable.

Comment: It means that you have some strings with some other characters (such as `88+2,`) which make the evaluation fail. Try to clean first the column and see if you can spot where the error is. Otherwise you can always try just catch the errors in a try/except statement iterating over the rows

Comment: Each of those cell values is a string, e.g. "88+2"..  While your sample should all `eval`, it is likely that one or more is a not a valid Python.  You'll need to examine more, if not all, of the `df.LS` to find it.

Comment: When I ran the lines you suggested, I got something like this along with the malformed statement:  

[88 +2 ,91 +3 ,84 +3 ,82 +3  ...] <- Syntax Error 

It appears that there is an extra space that messes everything up.

To combat this, I performed the following:

original_df["LS"]= original_df["LS"].str.replace(" ","")
(original_df['LS'].str.len() == 4).count() gave 14743
len(original_df['LS']) gave 14743 as well

it seems like all the white spaces have gone but still 'malformed statement' is coming